# I want to wait until the key in the loop is equal to the value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a translator, and I want to write executable conjugation code. I have this function that splits the sentence into array with words:

```js
function conj() {
    let sentence = document.getElementById("id").value.split(" ").filter(item => item != "")
    let final = [];
    for (let word of sentence) {
        for (let key in EnAdjectives) {
            console.log(word, key)
        }
    }
}
```

When I wrote `console.log` to check what *word* and *key* I have at the moment,I got this [console.log words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUi4q.png). So I need to stop loop if word equals key and next word belongs to the *EnMaleNouns* or *EnFemaleNouns* object, etc.

Comment: I can't see anything in your code that wouldn't work, what is the problem? Unless the `word` is not in `EnMaleNouns` etc.

Comment: Yes, probably this's a problem, maybe i should make many loops for every kind of noun?

Comment: `next word belongs to object of EnMaleNouns||EnFemaleNouns etc` do you mean word matches keys or values of these objects??

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but could the issue be that the `continue` statements do go to the next iteration of the loop of `EnAdjectives` even though you want to continue with the next word in the sentence?

Comment: No, i tried break; ,without  nothing, but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1):

Op's statement

> I want to stop loop if word == key and next word belongs to object of
>   EnMaleNouns||EnFemaleNouns etc

Try using `for loop` for iterating words to get `index`.With `index` in hand we can check the condition of next word being in `EnMaleNouns` or `ElFemaleNouns`

```
 for (let i=0;i<sentence.length;i++) {
        for (let key in EnAdjectives) {
              if(sentence[i]== key && 
                 sentence[i+1] && 
              (sentence[i+1] in EnMaleNouns 
               ||sentence[i+1] in  EnFemaleNouns)){

              //do something here
             //break by return
                return
             }
            //your other if conditions
        }
 }
```

Comment: I checked your example and it has one bug. For example, if the adjective is further than the first one (beautiful), I get an error, but for the first adjective, everything works well.

Comment: just i get "else" result, so how to make loop check EVERY adjective in an object?

Comment: make this independent if block ..dont attach it to if else chain of your code

Comment: Could you say, what second "(" means?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking. Second ( is to wrap the condition of "Or"